# Segmentation fault while separating tokens from a string

Tags: c, unix

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[]) 
{
char *args[10]; 
int i=0;
char str[41], teststr[41];  //two arrays declared here
const char delimiter[2]=" ";
printf("Enter command:");
scanf("%s", str);
memcpy(teststr, str, sizeof(str));  
args[i]=strtok(teststr, delimiter); 
while(args[i]!=NULL)                
{                                   
printf("args[%d]=%s", i, args[i]); 
i++;
args[i]=strtok(teststr, delimiter);
}
return 0;
}
```

memcpy() is a function to copy one array to another.
strtok() is a function to split string into tokens .
We will loop it continuously until there are no tokens left in the string.
Each token is stored in 'argv[]' which is a char array.

Comment: In your second call to strtok, change teststr to NULL.  Also, instead of checking whether args[i] is null, check i against argc.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/: `In subsequent calls, the function expects a null pointer ... `

Comment: Part of the `strok` man page says: "In each subsequent call that should parse the same string, str should be NULL.". You pass `teststr` each time, thus the loop will likely never end (i.e., `args[i]` will never be `NULL`.

Comment: You did not ask a question.

Comment: `"%s"` does not contain spaces in its contents.

Comment: Yes, I don't know how did I miss that but when in subsequent calls to strtok() inside while() loop I pass NULL instead of teststr this time, the loop exits after one cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The while loop will run infinitely as the `arg[i]` which is first token keep on making while condition pass leading to infinite.

Since you are using `scanf()` to read into string, if the string is multi word it cannot read making your code cannot parse all the tokens but only first word. I suggest you to use `fgets()` as below to read multi word string,

```
if (fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin) == NULL) {
   ;  // handle EOF
}
```

Here is the working code [ideone](http://ideone.com/tj6jCi).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will remove the segfault for you but you're not calling `strtok` right. You only pass the delimiter on the first call to it. On subsequent calls to it, the second argument should be `NULL`. The way you are currently calling it is bound to break things for you.

Comment: Actually the man page says, "On the first call to strtok() the string to be parsed should be specified in 'str'.  In each subsequent call that should parse the same string, 'str' should be NULL."
Here 'str' is first parameter and 'delimiter' is second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Please change `while..loop` by

```
while(args[i]!=NULL)                
{                                   
       printf("args[%d]=%s", i, args[i]); 
       i++;
       args[i]=strtok(NULL, delimiter);
}
```

you not need to every time to pass `teststr` in `strtok` otherwise `while...loop` goes to infinite loop.

Comment: Yes I did that but then the loop executed only once

Comment: @user1478588 yes right but it depend on what you give input in `scanf` can you give which string you give in input to `scanf`.Also why you take array for `args` only `char *args` is enough.

Comment: Actually I am making a shell. So when I write commands such as 'cat shell.c' then args[0]='cat' and args[1]='shell.c'

Comment: @user1478588 also you must modify your `scanf` function which allow space in input make it like `scanf("%10[0-9a-zA-Z ]s", str);`